# Oracle Truncate Parent table constraint error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, truncate

Parent table A with some records.
Child table B with 0 records.

I have a cursor to do truncation on these tables in reverse tree order (i.e. truncate child first, then parent)
But I'm still getting this error when I truncate the parent table 'ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys' error, despite the fact that the child table has no records at all.

However, when I do 'Delete from ' in the same order, all constraint related errors were avoided. And 'Delete from' takes really long time to run.

I don't want to disable or drop any constraints.

Comment: What Oracle version are you using?

Comment: I'm using oracle 12c

Comment: Then you can use the `TRUNCATE TABLE parent CASCADE` command in Lalit's answer.

Comment: I don't have the 'ON DELETE CASCADE' clause defined.

Comment: Hi again, in this case, would disable pk constraint suffice? Or should I disable all foreign key constraints that relate to this pk?

Comment: The primary keys are ok while truncating, only the foreign keys hurt. So, yes, disable all foreign keys.

Comment: but I thought if I simply disable the PK, then all the 'enabled' FK constraint have nothing to reference

Comment: No, you cannot disable a pk which is used by an enabled fk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, when I do 'Delete from ' in the same order, all constraint related errors were avoided.

That's the only way if you have constraints enabled. You cannot truncate. If you still want to truncate the table, then you could find the `constraint name` from `user_constraints`, and then `DISABLE` them:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Then you could `TRUNCATE` the table, and re-enable the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENABLE CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

If your table has `ON DELETE CASCADE` option, then from Oracle `12.1` onward, you could use:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE table_name CASCADE;
```

Note, both the `DELETE CASCADE` and the `TRUNCATE CASCADE` will fail if any of the relationships in the hierarchy are not defined with the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause.

Comment: Thank you Lalit. Yeah, I guess disable the constraint is the only option for me. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to delete from parent/child tables:

```
CREATE TABLE par (i NUMBER CONSTRAINT par_pk PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE chi (i NUMBER CONSTRAINT chi_fk REFERENCES par(i) ON DELETE CASCADE);
INSERT INTO par VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO chi VALUES(1);
```

1) If you have Oracle 12 or later, and you have foreign keys with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you can use [TRUNCATE CASCADE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNCATE-TABLE.html#GUID-B76E5846-75B5-4876-98EC-439E15E4D8A4), which I expect to be the fastest option:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE par CASCADE;
Table PAR truncated.

SELECT count(*) FROM par;
0

SELECT count(*) FROM chi;
0
```

2) If your foreign keys are defined with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, you can use `DELETE`, which I expect to be the slowest option:

```
DELETE FROM par;
1 row deleted.

SELECT count(*) FROM par;
0

SELECT count(*) FROM chi;
0
```

3) Otherwise, you can disable the foreign keys, truncate the tables and reenable the foreign keys. This is fast, but is a little bit more risky than the other options (please check that the constraints are all valid afterwards):

```
ALTER TABLE chi DISABLE CONSTRAINT chi_fk;
TRUNCATE TABLE chi;
TRUNCATE TABLE par;
ALTER TABLE chi ENABLE  CONSTRAINT chi_fk;
```

AFAIK, it is not possible to alter a foreign key from normal to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I guess you have to drop and recreate them:

```
ALTER TABLE chi DROP CONSTRAINT chi_fk;
ALTER TABLE chi ADD  CONSTRAINT chi_fk REFERENCES par(i) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. your points are valid. I think disabling the constraint is the only option for me. And sorry, I had to pick Lalit since he answered first. Thank you again.

Comment: @Dozel, that's fine. At work I disable the constraints, too.

Comment: @wolφi Thanks for extending a bit on my answer +1. I too disable constraints while developing or testing something. Or, at times I keep the delete statements ready to avoid spedning more time. However, I restrict this practice to `dev/test` environments only. It's not an easy task in `prod`, even if we want to do it, a lot of integration testing is required as we won't know what session/process might be impacting it. If at all it needs to be done in `PROD`, then do it when you are sure there won't be any active database sessions or any process manipulating the database. Stay safe :-)

Comment: @Lalit Kumar B, Hi again, in this case, would disable pk constraint suffice? Or should I disable all foreign key constraints that relate to this pk?